# SQL Server, Qlik Sense naming convention

Tags: sql-server, qlikview, qliksense

Is there any naming convention for Qlik Sense? I'm creating database in SQL Server which will be conected to Qlik Sense. I've noticed that some names are automatically changed.

For exmaple I have table which has `Id` column, and `Country` foreign key column. In Qlik `Country` was changed to `Country.ID`.

I don't know much about Qlik hence my question. What is the naming convention and what should I watch out for to make Qlik programmer life's easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one thing is that the best is that common/joined fields have the same names, for example not "Id" but "ProductId", "ShopId"m "CountryId" etc. as QlikView uses associative technology to connect them by default.

but it is not obligatory as everything can be changed in QlikSense during import and field names can be set there using "as" syntax in preceding load.